# Phone Auth with firebase never got a verification code

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase to do the phone auth and when I run the app on my real phone and type my real number never got any code and this shows up on the logcat

```
 com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verifythat the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ App validation failed ]
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzce.zzb(Unknown Source:171)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdf.zza(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdg.run(Unknown Source:36)
```

I have checked the package name and the SHA-1 are both correct

Comment: sure I edited the post

Comment: Did you try anything to solve it? There are a lot of stackoverflow questions currently with this exact same error.

Comment: most of them says check the SHA1 code are match with the one on firebase or re-synce the project and I did both but still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

The reason was connecting firebase from android studio
tools>firebase

It worked when I create a new project and did it manually